# how to execute the javascript returned by AJAX response in the webpage (response = html+javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

my buyresult.php page is working properly when i give give the url as buyresult.php?q=Mysore
but the in response i get after ajax call(both html and javascript is response).. the javascript is not working... how to solve it.. I'm new to web programming. Please HELP..
I've googled and got the result as to use

```
new Ajax.Updater(divID,URL,{asynchronous:true,evalScripts: true});
```

but i don't know where to put this function
my index.php file is as follows :

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","buyresult.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
}
</script></head>
<body>

<label for="city">Enter City :</label><input class="w-input" id="city" type="text" placeholder="Enter the city name (required)" name="city" data-name="city" required="required" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<div id="txtHint"><b>Results will be displayed Here...</b></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try using a library helping with common javascript operations. One of most famous:
https://jquery.com/

Comment: I don't know jquery.. how can it be done ?